# ASP MVC DropDownList error "Converting to Type"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Hey, I have a table with 2 fields of type int which are "StatusID" and "TypeID". TypeID works correctly but StatusID returns an error. Here's what my controller looks like:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Create(Project project)
{

    var db = new DB();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        try
        {
            db.Projects.InsertOnSubmit(project);
            db.SubmitChanges();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(project);
        }
    }


    ViewData["Status"] = from c in db.Status
                         select new SelectListItem
                             {
                                 Text = c.Text,
                                 Value = c.StatusID.ToString()
                             };

    ViewData["Types"] = from t in db.Project_Types
                        select new SelectListItem
                            {
                                Text = t.Text,
                                Value = t.TypeID.ToString()
                            };
    return View(project);
}
```

The error I get is:

> Message = "The parameter conversion from type 'System.String' to type 'ConstructionProject.Models.Status' failed because no TypeConverter can convert between these types."

But like I said, the database model for the field "TypeID" and "StatusID" are identical.

Edit:

### DB Schema:

**Table Project**

```
ProjectID   int
TypeID      int
StatusID    int
Name        varchar(50)
Description text
DateCreated datetime
ClientID    int
Contractor  int
```

**Table Status**

```
StatusID    int
Text        varchar(50)
```

**Table Project Type**

```
TypeID      int
Text        varchar(50)
```

Anyone knows what would correct the issue here?

My View Page (after changing to StatusID):

```
        <p>
            <label for="Status">Status:</label>
            <%= Html.DropDownList("StatusID")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("StatusID", "*")%>
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Types">Type:</label>
            <%= Html.DropDownList("Types")%>
            <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Types", "*")%>
        </p>
```

Comment: So, where exactly are you getting this error? I am guessing, it could be in the View code where you could be assuming ViewData["Status"] to be of a type Status, whereas you are passing in a string from the controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a shot in the dark:  in your view, you've given the Status select list an ID of "Status", which, when you post a set of form data, causes the default form collection mapping to try to convert the selected value for the list (which is a string version of your int StatusID) into a ConstructionProject.Models.Status *object*, which fails.  Try using "StatusID" for the ID of your select list and see if that works.

For better answers, you should post the relevant parts of your view markup as well.

Comment: After changing it to StatusID, I get: The ViewData item with the key 'StatusID' is of type 'System.Int32' but needs to be of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'.

Comment: Well, I just changed the name to something completely different and it worked. I guess I'll need to read more on ViewData object. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Alex, I don't think your issue is with ViewData -- your problem is occurring when the user's form input values are being mapped to the Project object.  This process is called Model Binding, and here's a great article on it: http://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple Forms in your view, make sure you are explicitly setting the 'action' attribute of the Form by using the correct overload of the BeginForm method. That is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ACTION_METHOD", "CONTROLLER", FormMethod.Post, null))
```

Instead of this one:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your error may be due to having "Status" somewhere in your code instead of "StatusId."  Notice the error says it is trying to convert to Status, not StatusId.

I ran into this on a project of mine.  If you're using Entity Framework, and your object has a foreign key, EF is also going to create a reference to the foreign object for you (forgive me if I'm not describing this accurately).  When you type "MyObject." in code, Intellisense will provide you with both Status and StatusId.

In my case, I used DropDownListFor() with model.PersonType instead of model.PersonTypeId.