# ASP MVC DropDownList returns 0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

Hey, following my struggles with the MVC DropDownList [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1956532/asp-mvc-dropdownlist-error-converting-to-type), it seems that my DropDownList always returns 0 when I submit the form. I still have the same code as the other thread.

[image]

Is it because the Status and Type Tables are not linked together in the code? I really don't know where to start to look for the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: Is the ID of your dropdownlist StatusID now?

Comment: @Terje might want to put this in an answer that you can accept so that everyone can see it.

Comment: @AlexDemers - you might want to add an answer and accept it so that this doesn't continue to show up in the 'unanswered' list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been answered by Terje in the comment of my original post. The name of the fields needs to match those of the table.

Comment: I wish it was easier to see when someone answers your comments :)